# WCF web API hosted in IIS

Tags: iis, wcf-web-api

I want to try out WCF web API. My plan is to create an application hosted on IIS that runs by itself (not combined with an MVC 3 application, etc). Maybe I'll give it an address http://192.168.1.2/myapi.

How do I set up my project from the beginning?

Which project template should I choose? WCF service application, ASP.NET empty web application, or what?

Then I guess I should nuget WebApi.All?

Then I should edit web.config?

Then I should put something in global.asax?

What else?

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a getting started series on WCF Web API:
http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2011/04/15/Microsoft-Web-API-e28093-the-REST-is-done-by-WCF-(Part-1).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the following post, where I describe how to host WCF Web API with IIS - http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/wcf-web-apiiis-hosting/